# import annotation based spring project in xml based project

Tags: java, spring-framework-beans

I have two spring projects,

Project A: is built using xml bean confguration.

Project B : is built using Annotations;
and A depends on B;

how can I load B beans inside the A applicationContext.

I searched but I found how to load xml beans using annotations : `@ImportResource`

Is there a way to do so without having to create two application context :

```
ApplicationContext applicationContextA = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/applicationContextA.xml");

ApplicationContext applicationContextB = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BConfiguration.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, You Can Use One Application Context

You can use a combination of both xml and annotation based configuration using either ApplicationContext implementation. So you can choose one and implement it using one of the following methods.

#### With ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

When using xml you want to activate package scanning in your xml file.

In the xml:

```xml
<context:component-scan base-package="com.yourdomain.packetstoscan"/>
<bean id="myXmlConfiguredBean" class="com.yourdomain.MyXmlConfiguredBean"/>
```

#### With AnnotationConfigApplicationContext

When using annotations you want to include the xml file with an annotation on your config class.

In your Java configuration class:

```java
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:yourContext.xml")
public class MyAnnotationConfiguredBean { }
```

#### Bean Creation Order

*When testing this I noticed just one minor difference, which was the bean creation order. However, I do not think this should have any influence on your application. I'm just adding this for the sake of completeness.*

For Xml based config:

```
INFO com.yourdomain.MyXmlApp - BEAN: myAnnotationConfiguredBean
INFO com.yourdomain.MyXmlApp - BEAN: org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor
INFO com.yourdomain.MyXmlApp - BEAN: org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor
INFO com.yourdomain.MyXmlApp - BEAN: org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor
INFO com.yourdomain.MyXmlApp - BEAN: org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory
INFO com.yourdomain.MyXmlApp - BEAN: myXmlConfiguredBean
```

For Annotation based:

```
INFO com.yourdomain.MyApp - BEAN: org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor
INFO com.yourdomain.MyApp - BEAN: org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor
INFO com.yourdomain.MyApp - BEAN: org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor
INFO com.yourdomain.MyApp - BEAN: org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory
INFO com.yourdomain.MyApp - BEAN: myAnnotationConfiguredBean
INFO com.yourdomain.MyApp - BEAN: myXmlConfiguredBean
```